# Отменить выбранный объект

Tags: javafx

Есть TextArea, если нажать на него и потом, по самой сцене, то текстовое поле остается активным и туда можно вводить текст. Как сделать так, чтобы при нажатие на сцену снималось это выделение и поле было не активным? Может есть у кого идея, как сделать это. У меня есть мысль, о том что это делается через 
название_сцены.setOnMouseClicked(event -> {и вот сюда, что-то надо добавить.});
[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Либо поведение, описанное вами смахивает на баг, либо вы не совсем явно предоставили суть вопроса.

1. При клике вне формы TextArea каретка становится неактивной, соответственно, при наборе текста символы туда попадать не будут, если поведение обратное - это очень смахивает на баг.
2. Если требуется полностью запретить дальнейший ввод символов при клике вне формы, то сделать это будет несложно:

```java
package com.sad.controllers;

import javafx.fxml.FXML;
import javafx.scene.control.TextArea;
import javafx.scene.input.MouseEvent;

public class testController {

    //объявляем переменную TextArea
    @FXML
    private TextArea ourTextArea;
    //Описываем MouseEvent
    @FXML
    void disableTextInput(MouseEvent event) {
        //обращаемся к editableProperty и задаём флаг false
        ourTextArea.editableProperty().setValue(false);
    }
}
```

Comment: Удаление name_Text.area.setEditable(true); помогло.